# Is there a reliable alternative to NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad, nsurlconnection

My app is calling a web service to retrieve some data, and I want to make the experience as best as possible. I figured out that using `NSURLConnection` it's very hard to give good timely feedback.

Sometimes my iPhone tries to load the data for a minute or two and I see no way of figuring out what is taking so long, or why the download is so troublesome. Then after a few minutes I sometimes end up with an error code.

I'd like to display exactly what is happening. Messages like:

1. "Establishing internet connection"
2. "Trying to connect to server"
3. "Connected..."
4. "Downloading data..."
5. "Download complete!"

And when there is trouble like server not reachable or DNS could not be resolved, it would be nice to just try again a few times and not simply quit and throw error.

Are there replacements for `NSURLConnection` which handle these things more gracefully and give better in-time feedback about what is happening?

Comment: You have looked at [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) right? It gives you a lot of those callbacks but may be considered complicated.

Comment: You can do 3, 4, 5 with the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Something](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) that can help you achieve what you want. Since `ASIHTTPRequest` is no longer being supported MKNetworkKit would be your best choice. To check for connectivity, you can always use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 4):

I've been a big fan of the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) library. Very easy to use and wraps all your networking calls in blocks that are very easy to work with.

It is also is kept very current, so you should be safe in getting all the updates it needs as your project progresses and ages.

Comment: Thanks! Does it provide timely feedback about what is happening? Delegate calls or notifications?

Comment: It doesn't use delegate methods, it uses blocks. So you start your connection and you have a success block and a fail block. The method will continue on, but when the connection is done, it will perform any logic inside the success/fail blocks. You can always create your own delegate method to call from inside those blocks. That is what I do. Then you have complete control over who is getting notified.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be misusing NSURLConnection and NSURLConnectionDelegate, since you can do most of you needs with them.

But, what about [MKNetworkKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/)? I've been using it and it really makes those kind of issues easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks! Does it provide timely feedback about what is happening? Delegate calls or notifications?